# Chrome Developer Tools on Angular API priority

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I am calling my API calls in `Angular` with a priority value. Kindly refer to the following code.
But in Chrome Developer Tools, where can I see that priority value in the Network tab?

```
$http.get("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld20?test=hari", {
    priority:20
}).then(function(response) {
});
```

Comment: Fixed typography and improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Look at the right side of the network tab and click the 'Reponse' tab  beside the 'Timing'  tab